# Input data preparation for lstm/gru

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm, data-preprocessing

I am having problems in understanding how to transform my data to  feed to network(i think lstm network helps as my data is mostly time series type and also has some temporal information so..).

Here is the dataformat[image]
first 6  columns represent one second of data(larger_corr, shorter_corr,noiseratio,x,y,z)
and then corresponding output feature followed by next second data.

But in order to prepare data for training how can i make send 6 columns of data and then next 6 columns.All the columns are length of 40.

I am not sure if i expressed it clear enough

Please let me know if you need any other information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to prepare your data as follows, but note that I only use 12 columns to ensure readability:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import tabulate
np.random.seed(0)

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'larger_corr' : np.random.randn(25),
    'shorter_corr' : np.random.randn(25),
    'noiseratio' : np.random.randn(25),
    'x' : np.random.randn(25),
    'y' : np.random.randn(25),
    'z' : np.random.randn(25),
    'output' : np.random.randint(0,2,25),
    'larger_corr.1' : np.random.randn(25),
    'shorter_corr.1' : np.random.randn(25),
    'noiseratio.1' : np.random.randn(25),
    'x.1' : np.random.randn(25),
    'y.1' : np.random.randn(25),
    'z.1' : np.random.randn(25),
    'output.1' : np.random.randint(0,2,25)
})

print(df.to_markdown())
y1, y2 = df.pop('output').to_numpy(), df.pop('output.1').to_numpy()
data = df.to_numpy()
x1, x2 = np.array_split(data, 2, axis=1)
x1 = np.expand_dims(x1, axis=1) # add timestep dimension
x2 = np.expand_dims(x2, axis=1) # add timestep dimension
X = np.concatenate([x1, x2])
Y = np.concatenate([y1, y1])
print('Shape of X -->', X.shape, 'Shape of labels -->', Y.shape)
```

```
|    |   larger_corr |   shorter_corr |   noiseratio |          x |         y |          z |   output |   larger_corr.1 |   shorter_corr.1 |   noiseratio.1 |        x.1 |        y.1 |         z.1 |   output.1 |
|---:|--------------:|---------------:|-------------:|-----------:|----------:|-----------:|---------:|----------------:|-----------------:|---------------:|-----------:|-----------:|------------:|-----------:|
|  0 |      1.76405  |     -1.45437   |   -0.895467  | -0.68481   |  1.88315  | -0.149635  |        1 |       0.438871  |       -0.244179  |     -0.891895  | -0.617166  |  1.14367   | -0.936916   |          0 |
|  1 |      0.400157 |      0.0457585 |    0.386902  | -0.870797  | -1.34776  | -0.435154  |        1 |       0.63826   |        0.475261  |      0.570081  | -1.77556   | -0.188056  | -1.97935    |          0 |
|  2 |      0.978738 |     -0.187184  |   -0.510805  | -0.57885   | -1.27048  |  1.84926   |        0 |       2.01584   |       -0.714216  |      2.66323   | -1.11821   |  1.24678   |  0.445384   |          0 |
|  3 |      2.24089  |      1.53278   |   -1.18063   | -0.311553  |  0.969397 |  0.672295  |        0 |      -0.243653  |       -1.18694   |      0.410289  | -1.60639   | -0.253884  | -0.195333   |          1 |
|  4 |      1.86756  |      1.46936   |   -0.0281822 |  0.0561653 | -1.17312  |  0.407462  |        1 |       1.53384   |        0.608891  |      0.485652  | -0.814676  | -0.870176  | -0.202716   |          1 |
|  5 |     -0.977278 |      0.154947  |    0.428332  | -1.16515   |  1.94362  | -0.769916  |        1 |       0.76475   |        0.504223  |      1.31153   |  0.321281  |  0.0196537 |  0.219389   |          0 |
|  6 |      0.950088 |      0.378163  |    0.0665172 |  0.900826  | -0.413619 |  0.539249  |        0 |      -2.45668   |       -0.513996  |     -0.235649  | -0.12393   | -1.11437   | -1.03016    |          0 |
|  7 |     -0.151357 |     -0.887786  |    0.302472  |  0.465662  | -0.747455 | -0.674333  |        1 |      -1.70365   |        0.818475  |     -1.48018   |  0.0221213 |  0.607842  | -0.929744   |          0 |
|  8 |     -0.103219 |     -1.9808    |   -0.634322  | -1.53624   |  1.92294  |  0.0318306 |        1 |       0.420153  |        1.1566    |     -0.0214848 | -0.321287  |  0.457237  | -2.55857    |          1 |
|  9 |      0.410599 |     -0.347912  |   -0.362741  |  1.48825   |  1.48051  | -0.635846  |        1 |      -0.298149  |       -0.803689  |      1.05279   |  0.692618  |  0.875539  |  1.6495     |          0 |
| 10 |      0.144044 |      0.156349  |   -0.67246   |  1.89589   |  1.86756  |  0.676433  |        1 |       0.263602  |       -0.551562  |     -0.117402  | -0.353524  |  0.346481  |  0.611738   |          0 |
| 11 |      1.45427  |      1.23029   |   -0.359553  |  1.17878   |  0.906045 |  0.576591  |        1 |       0.731266  |       -0.332414  |      1.82851   |  0.81229   | -0.454874  | -1.05194    |          1 |
| 12 |      0.761038 |      1.20238   |   -0.813146  | -0.179925  | -0.861226 | -0.208299  |        1 |       0.22807   |        1.84452   |     -0.0166771 | -1.14179   |  0.198095  | -0.754946   |          0 |
| 13 |      0.121675 |     -0.387327  |   -1.72628   | -1.07075   |  1.91006  |  0.396007  |        0 |      -2.02852   |       -0.422776  |      1.87011   | -0.287549  |  0.391408  |  0.623188   |          1 |
| 14 |      0.443863 |     -0.302303  |    0.177426  |  1.05445   | -0.268003 | -1.09306   |        0 |       0.96619   |        0.487659  |     -0.380307  |  1.31554   | -3.17786   |  0.00470758 |          0 |
| 15 |      0.333674 |     -1.04855   |   -0.401781  | -0.403177  |  0.802456 | -1.49126   |        1 |      -0.186922  |       -0.375828  |      0.428698  |  0.685781  | -0.956575  | -0.899891   |          0 |
| 16 |      1.49408  |     -1.42002   |   -1.6302    |  1.22245   |  0.947252 |  0.439392  |        0 |      -0.472325  |        0.227851  |      0.361896  |  0.524599  | -0.0312749 |  0.129242   |          1 |
| 17 |     -0.205158 |     -1.70627   |    0.462782  |  0.208275  | -0.15501  |  0.166673  |        1 |       1.93666   |        0.703789  |      0.467568  | -0.793387  |  1.03272   |  0.979693   |          1 |
| 18 |      0.313068 |      1.95078   |   -0.907298  |  0.976639  |  0.614079 |  0.635031  |        0 |       1.47734   |       -0.7978    |     -1.51803   | -0.237881  | -1.21562   |  0.328375   |          0 |
| 19 |     -0.854096 |     -0.509652  |    0.0519454 |  0.356366  |  0.922207 |  2.38314   |        0 |      -0.0848901 |       -0.6759    |     -1.89304   |  0.569498  | -0.318678  |  0.487074   |          0 |
| 20 |     -2.55299  |     -0.438074  |    0.729091  |  0.706573  |  0.376426 |  0.944479  |        1 |       0.427697  |       -0.922546  |     -0.785087  | -1.51061   |  1.49513   |  0.144842   |          1 |
| 21 |      0.653619 |     -1.2528    |    0.128983  |  0.0105    | -1.0994   | -0.912822  |        1 |      -0.30428   |       -0.448586  |     -1.60529   | -1.56505   | -0.130251  | -0.0856099  |          1 |
| 22 |      0.864436 |      0.77749   |    1.1394    |  1.78587   |  0.298238 |  1.11702   |        1 |       0.204625  |        0.181979  |      1.43184   | -3.05123   | -1.20289   |  0.71054    |          1 |
| 23 |     -0.742165 |     -1.6139    |   -1.23483   |  0.126912  |  1.32639  | -1.31591   |        1 |      -0.0833382 |       -0.220084  |     -1.94219   |  1.55966   |  0.199565  |  0.93096    |          0 |
| 24 |      2.26975  |     -0.21274   |    0.402342  |  0.401989  | -0.694568 | -0.461585  |        1 |       1.82893   |        0.0249562 |      1.13995   | -2.63101   |  0.393166  |  0.875074   |          0 |
Shape of X --> (50, 1, 6) Shape of labels --> (50,)
```

After preprocessing your data, you can create a `LSTM` model like this, where the dimension `timesteps` represents 1 second:

```py
timesteps, features = X.shape[1], X.shape[2]
input = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(timesteps, features))
x = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(32, return_sequences=False)(input)
output = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(x)
model = tf.keras.Model(input, output)
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy())
print(model.summary())
model.fit(X, Y, batch_size=10, epochs=5)
```

```
Model: "model_1"
_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 input_16 (InputLayer)       [(None, 1, 6)]            0         
                                                                 
 lstm_1 (LSTM)               (None, 32)                4992      
                                                                 
 dense_21 (Dense)            (None, 1)                 33        
                                                                 
=================================================================
Total params: 5,025
Trainable params: 5,025
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
None
Epoch 1/5
5/5 [==============================] - 2s 4ms/step - loss: 0.6914
Epoch 2/5
5/5 [==============================] - 0s 3ms/step - loss: 0.6852
Epoch 3/5
5/5 [==============================] - 0s 3ms/step - loss: 0.6806
Epoch 4/5
5/5 [==============================] - 0s 4ms/step - loss: 0.6758
Epoch 5/5
5/5 [==============================] - 0s 4ms/step - loss: 0.6705
<keras.callbacks.History at 0x7f90ca6c6d90>
```

You can also scale / normalize your data before feeding it to the model using [MinMaxScaler](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler.html) or [StandardScaler](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.html#sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler), but I will leave that up to you.